# Click on item animates and display info-window for related marker on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

### **code explanation**

1.declared `animateMarker` function inside the viewModel with one parameter which is `marker`.

2.declared `populateInfoWindow`inside the viewModel with three parameters (marker, infowindow, element) and call `animateMarker` function inside it.

3.call `populateInfoWindow` inside click event listener inside a loop that iterates over locations.

4.added data-bind : "click : $root.populateInfoWindow " to `<li  data-bind : "click : $root.populateInfoWindow >`

**the error**

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Also neither marker is animated nor infowindo is dispayed. while clicking on the list item.
Is there other recommended approach for this issue or idea to handle that error.

---

app.js

//model contains required data about locations

```
var model = [

    {
        title: 'Park Ave Penthouse',
        latLng: {
            lat: 40.7713024,
            lng: -73.9632393
        }
    },
    {
        title: 'Chelsea Loft',
        latLng: {
            lat: 40.7444883,
            lng: -73.9949465
        }
    },
    {
        title: 'Union Square Open Floor Plan',
        latLng: {
            lat: 40.7347062,
            lng: -73.9895759
        }
    },
    {
        title: 'East Village Hip Studio',
        latLng: {
            lat: 40.7281777,
            lng: -73.984377
        }
    },
    {
        title: 'TriBeCa Artsy Bachelor Pad',
        latLng: {
            lat: 40.7195264,
            lng: -74.0089934
        }
    },
    {
        title: 'Chinatown Homey Space',
        latLng: {
            lat: 40.7180628,
            lng: -73.9961237
        }
    }

];
//declaring global variables 
var infoWindow, map;

function initMap() {
    //initialize the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: model[3].latLng,
        zoom: 12
    });


    myViewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel)

};



function ViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    this.filter = ko.observable();
    this.places = ko.observableArray(model);
    self.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // self.marker = [];
    model.forEach(function(element) {
        var position = element.latLng;
        var title = element.title;

        element.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            title: title,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        });
        // self.marker.push(element.marker);
        element.marker.addListener('click', function() {
            self.populateInfoWindow(this, self.infowindow, element);
        });

    });

    self.populateInfoWindow = (function(marker, infowindow, element) {

        self.infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + element.title + '</strong><br>');
        self.infowindow.open(map, marker);
        self.animateMarker(marker);

    });
    self.animateMarker = (function(marker) {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        setTimeout(function() {
            marker.setAnimation(null)
        }, 1500);
    });
    this.visibleLocations = ko.computed(function() {
        var filter = self.filter();
        if (!filter) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.places(), function(item) {
                item.marker.setVisible(true);
            });
            return self.places();
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.places(), function(item) {
                // set all markers visible (false)
                var result = (item.title.toLowerCase().search(filter) >= 0);
                item.marker.setVisible(result);
                return result;
            });
        }

    });

};

//loading google maps error handling 

function googleError() {

    alert("check your internet connection and reload the page");


}
```

---

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Nighbour hood map </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="search-menu ">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded justify-content-between">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand"> Find your favorite place</h1>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" data-bind="textInput: filter">
            </form>
        </nav>

        <ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: visibleLocations">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-bind="text: title, click :$root.populateInfoWindow"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="map"></div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCX6bSgdTWvavwA0O8B7KsObZhE5GAf6yQ&callback=initMap" / onerror="googleError()" async defer>
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That error goes away if you type 'marker.title' instead of 'element.title' in your populateInfoWindow() method. However you then get a google map related error, which I have no idea how to solve...

Comment: oh ! it was because elemet here out side the forEach loop do it is undefined
changed element to element.title while calling populateInfowindo

Comment: any other idea how to link between click on list and marker animatoin ? @Ray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `InfoWindow.open` method expects `MVCObject` object (marker object in this example) for a second parameter, `click` event binding needs to be changed from:

```
data-bind="click: $root.populateInfoWindow"
```

to this one:

```
data-bind="click: $root.populateInfoWindow.bind(this,$data.marker,$root.infowindow)"
```

> This way (via [`bind` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) both `marker` and `infoWindow`
>   parameters are getting passed to `populateInfoWindow` function

**Modified example**

```js
var model = [

    {
        title: 'Park Ave Penthouse',
        latLng: {
            lat: 40.7713024,
            lng: -73.9632393
        }
    },
    {
        title: 'Chelsea Loft',
        latLng: {
            lat: 40.7444883,
            lng: -73.9949465
        }
    },
    {
        title: 'Union Square Open Floor Plan',
        latLng: {
            lat: 40.7347062,
            lng: -73.9895759
        }
    },
    {
        title: 'East Village Hip Studio',
        latLng: {
            lat: 40.7281777,
            lng: -73.984377
        }
    },
    {
        title: 'TriBeCa Artsy Bachelor Pad',
        latLng: {
            lat: 40.7195264,
            lng: -74.0089934
        }
    },
    {
        title: 'Chinatown Homey Space',
        latLng: {
            lat: 40.7180628,
            lng: -73.9961237
        }
    }

];
//declaring global variables 
var infoWindow, map;

function initMap() {
    //initialize the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: model[3].latLng,
        zoom: 12
    });


    myViewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel)

};



function ViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    this.filter = ko.observable();
    this.places = ko.observableArray(model);
    self.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // self.marker = [];
    model.forEach(function (element) {
        var position = element.latLng;
        var title = element.title;

        element.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            title: title,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        });
        // self.marker.push(element.marker);
        element.marker.addListener('click', function () {
            self.populateInfoWindow(this, self.infowindow, element);
        });

    });

    self.populateInfoWindow = (function (marker, infowindow, element) {

        self.infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + marker.title + '</strong><br>');
        self.infowindow.open(map, marker);
        self.animateMarker(marker);

    });
    self.animateMarker = (function (marker) {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        setTimeout(function () {
            marker.setAnimation(null)
        }, 1500);
    });
    this.visibleLocations = ko.computed(function () {
        var filter = self.filter();
        if (!filter) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.places(), function (item) {
                item.marker.setVisible(true);
            });
            return self.places();
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.places(), function (item) {
                // set all markers visible (false)
                var result = (item.title.toLowerCase().search(filter) >= 0);
                item.marker.setVisible(result);
                return result;
            });
        }

    });

};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
#map {
            height: 140px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="search-menu ">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded justify-content-between">
        <h1 class="navbar-brand"> Find your favorite place</h1>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" data-bind="textInput: filter">
        </form>
    </nav>

    <ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: visibleLocations">
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-bind="text: title, click: $root.populateInfoWindow.bind(this,$data.marker,$root.infowindow)"></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div id="map"></div>
```